# How to use DataBinding through code behind?

Tags: silverlight

I have in xaml as following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 5 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
 <TextBox Text="LinkColor" VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="ColorCombo" MinWidth="180" Margin="5 0 0 0" SelectionChanged="ColorCombo_SelectionChanged">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Key}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="10" Width="20"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

---

This will create a label on the right side and a combo box on the right side.
The Itemssource for combo box will come from the code as:

```
ColorCombo.ItemsSource = ColorsDictionary;
```

Here colorsdictionary is defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, Color> ColorsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
```

But now, i am trying to add combo and the entire Itemtemplate through code. But I am not getting how to do( bind the data) through code, anyone can help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question you can create a `Binding` programatically like this:-

```
 TextBlock tb = new TextBlock;
 tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Key"));
```

However that isn't actually that useful to you.

The `DataTemplate` cannot be created in code in the manner above.   The only way to build a `DataTemplate` programmatically is to create a Xaml string (perhaps with the aid of `XDocument`) and then use `XamlReader` to load the generated Xaml.  Are you really sure you need to do all this programmatically?

Comment: Yes i need to do all these programmatically.
Let's say if i need not to do so, Can you tell me how to refer the Datatemplate defined in the Xaml in Code behind? I am not able to access resources defined in the App/xaml

Comment: @padmavathi:  I'm not sure I understand your supplementary question, you can access the `DataTemplate` in your Xaml with `ColorCombo.ItemsTemplate` but I don't think that helps you.